# Como puedo modificar atributos en mi txt?

Tags: java

Mi programa ya tiene el método para poder escribir los atributos en un archivo txt, quiero saber lo siguiente:
¿Cómo puedo añadirle 2 métodos, uno para no dejar que el usuario introduzca los mismos atributos que ya están escritos en el txt y otro método para poder modificar los datos dentro del programa?

Este es mi código:

```
public void Escribir()
    {
      File f = new File ("C:\\Users\\ferna\\Desktop\\SistemaLP");
       File archivo;
       FileWriter escribir;
       PrintWriter linea;
       archivo = new File("logings.txt");
       if(!archivo.exists()){
           try {
               RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f+"\\logings.txt", "rw");
               archivo.createNewFile();
               LU=TLU.getText();
               PU=TPU.getText();
               int NA = Integer.parseInt(TNA.getText());
               NU=TNU.getText();
               AU=TAU.getText();
               EU=TEU.getText();
               escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);
               linea = new PrintWriter(escribir);
               linea.println(LU+","+PU+","+NA+","+NU+":"+AU+":"+EU);
               linea.close();
               escribir.close();  
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Sistema.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       }else{
           try {
               RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f+"\\logings.txt", "rw");
               LU=TLU.getText();
               PU=TPU.getText();
               int NA = Integer.parseInt(TNA.getText());
               NU=TNU.getText();
               AU=TAU.getText();
               EU=TEU.getText();
               escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);
               linea = new PrintWriter(escribir);
               linea.println(LU+","+PU+","+NA+","+NU+":"+AU+":"+EU);
               linea.close();
               escribir.close(); 
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Sistema.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }  
      
       }
      
   }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu problema o error con este código? Por otra parte, ¿has considerado usar otro medio de almacenamiento como una base de datos por ejemplo? El problema es que tendrás que leer el archivo completo cada vez para verificar si el dato no existe, lo cual podría ser problemático, sobre en todo en contextos concurrentes o en archivos grandes. Sea como sea, dinos dónde está el problema, explicando el modo en que has decidido resolver esto.

Comment: Me fue requerido usar como base de datos archivos txt, por eso debo hacerlo de esa forma, no tengo problema ni error con el código, pregunte como puedo hacer eso dos métodos que puse arriba ya que no se como hacerlos.